# Is there a symbol for embedded manifold?

Tags: general-topology, field-theory

We say the symbol (or degrees of freedom) for a $0$-dimensional manifold (a point) embedded in $n$-dimensional space is $\mathbb{R}^n$ since it takes $n$ coordinates to describe such a point.

How would one write the degrees of freedom of an $n$-dimensional [surface topologically equivalent to a] sphere or $n$-dimensional ball embedded in $m$-dimensional space?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of any single symbol for such an object, but it's not hard to parameterize this space by hand.

For instance, an $n$-sphere living in $\mathbb{R}^m$ is determined (uniquely!) by

- a point (the center of the sphere)
- a positive real (the radius)
- a $n+1$-plane (e.g., the orientation of a cirlce in $\mathbb{R}^3$)

So you can say the space of $n$-spheres in $\mathbb{R}^m$ is parameterized by
$$\mathbb{R}^m \times \mathbb{R}_{\gt 0} \times \text{Gr}(n+1,m),$$
where (as usual) $\text{Gr}(k,n)$ is the [grassmannian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grassmannian), which parameterizes $k$ subspaces in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

The same parameterization also works for the space of all $n+1$ balls in $\mathbb{R}^m$, since every sphere is uniquely the boundary of some ball.

---

I hope this helps ^_^

Comment: More generally @OP, you may be interested in the term "**moduli space**." (Also: dangit, beat me to it! :P)

Comment: Goddamit, I meant a 'topological sphere' rather than a sphere. Oh well. I guess my fault for not being clear enough. Interesting answer none-the-less.